# How to modify each element of a list into a new list?

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I would like to learn how to do the following code using a => or ForEach or something else. It basically gets all elements of List1, modifies it, and then stores it into a new List2. List1 is not altered.

```
//List1 exists from before
List<string> List2 = new List<string>();
foreach (element in List1)
{
    List2.Add(element + " concact string");
}
```

Is there an easy way to write this code in a more concise/readable way?

Comment: `var List2 = List1.Select(element => element + " concat string").ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`System.Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netcore-3.1) extension method [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1), it's simple to select each item from `List1`, modify it, and return the results as a new `List<string>`:

```
List<string> List2 = List1.Select(element => element + " concat string").ToList();
```

Comment: The parameter of the 'Select' method here is called a Lambda Expression?

Comment: Yes, you can read more about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var newList = List1.Select(x => x.Concat(" concact string")).ToList();
```